# How to get in Angular2 the offSetTop of an element without using jQuery

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to create a directive that will fadeIn a photo slowly when an element is made visible. To do so, my first idea is comparing the position of an item regarding to the top (also checking the height of the window). But I can find how to do that with Angular2.

This is my code so far:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[fadeInPhoto]',
    host: {
        '(window:scroll)': 'onScroll()'
    }
})
export class FadeInPhotoDirective{
    private scrollTop: number;
    private initialClass: string;
    constructor(private _el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer){
        this.initialClass = 'thumbnail';
    }

    onScroll(){
        console.log('Photo top:', this._el);
    }
}
```

But this._el doesn't seem to have any method or property that contains that information.

Answer (score 31):

"offsetTop is relative to it's place in the document, not relative to the view port." -See link below

I was able to get the ACTUAL offsetTop from the top of the document using:

```
this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40877754/1742393

Answer (score 13):

The `Renderer` provides a selection of methods but AFAIK `offsetTop` is not one of them (they are all just to set values, not to get ones).

You can use instead:

```ts
this._el.nativeElement.offsetTop
```

Comment: for some reason it always returns 0. The element is at the bottom of the page (not visible yet), and after scrolling the element is visible... but the offSetTop always returns 0

Comment: Can you create a Plunker?

Comment: I'll try and I'll paste it here

Comment: @Fabiot try getting the offset in the ngOnInit method that you can implement

Comment: I have this exact same issue as @Fabiot. My ```private elementRef: ElementRef``` offsetTop is always 0.

Comment: Anyone who is always seeing 0, see my answer and it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like this:

- make sure to declare the element into the constructor, as "private":

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { ...}
- make sure you get the **offsetTop** after the element(s) already exist on the page:

  ngAfterViewInit() {
          console.log('el.nativeElement: ', this.el.nativeElement.offsetTop);
      }

Answer (score 1):

Try using a refrence in your template instead:

```
<div id='gallery-container' #galleryContainer class='gallery-image-container'>
    <div> <img src="../pic1"></div>
    <div> <img src="../pic2"></div>
    <div> <img src="../pic3"></div>

</div>
```

And use the ref name as the argument:

```
@ViewChild('galleryContainer') galleryContainer: ElementRef;
```

don't Forgot to mention that any view child thus declared is only available after the view is initialized. The first time this happens is in ngAfterViewInit (import and implement the AfterViewInit interface).

then in your template just call the method like this:

```
<div class="arrow " (click)="topArrowEffect()"  ></div>
```

and in your controller your method should be like this:

```
topArrowEffect(){
        this.galleryContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop =10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to access it like this:

```
this._el.nativeElement.offsetTop
```

Answer (score 0):

in html:

```
<div (click)="getPosition($event)">xxx</div>
```

in typescript:

```
getPosition(event){
    let offsetLeft = 0;
    let offsetTop = 0;

    let el = event.srcElement;

    while(el){
        offsetLeft += el.offsetLeft;
        offsetTop += el.offsetTop;
        el = el.parentElement;
    }
    return { offsetTop:offsetTop , offsetLeft:offsetLeft }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';


    @ViewChild("pageMenu")
      menuStickyElement;

     @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
      sticklyMenu() {
        // Get top height 
        this. offsetTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= this.menuStickyElement.nativeElement.offsetTop) {
          this.stickyNavMenu = true;
        } else {
          this.stickyNavMenu = false;
        }
      }
```