# How can you get current positional information about an element in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have the `ElementRef` of my navbar and I'm trying to find out how close it is to the top of my window so I can make it sticky

```
<div class="nav-bar" #navBar>

</div>

@ViewChild("navBar")
  navBarElement;
```

I'm printing out the positions of it's nativeElement in a scroll event but the values seem to be static

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll(event) {
   console.log("offset top", this.navBarElement.nativeElement.offsetTop);
}
```

How can I track the current position of my element?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`offsetTop` is relative to it's place in the document, not relative to the view port.

See [How to get an element's top position relative to the browser's window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350581/how-to-get-an-elements-top-position-relative-to-the-browsers-window) for how to get the scroll position.

eg. `var viewportOffset = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;`